# VSCode Terminal + Git Bash "command not found" for any command

Tags: visual-studio-code

My settings.json is very simple, it's replacing cmd.exe with sh.exe (from git).

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe"
}
```

Upon opening the shell, absolutely nothing works. I can't even ls.

```
sh.exe"-3.1$ ls
sh.exe": ls: command not found
sh.exe"-3.1$ cd ..
sh.exe"-3.1$ ls
sh.exe": ls: command not found
sh.exe"-3.1$
```

Does VSCode not work with Mingw32 (git's bash)? How do I set it up to work?

Answer (score 22):

So git bash requires two arguments --login and separately -i

Thus the full json needs to look like:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login","-i"]
}
```

This will cause all commands to work in the integrated terminal.

Comment: For those who cannot use bash aliases in vscode in windows, adding "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login","-i"] in settings worked. Make sure to F1> Reload Window after you do.