# Does VSCode come with git itself?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, visual-studio-code

The documentation says plain as day that VSCode does not come with git, that it leverages your machine's git installation and you must install it.

HOWEVER, it worked just fine for me. I only had github desktop and I am absolutely positively sure that I did not have git for windows installed and github desktop did not place itself in my PATH. (Technically I did have git on Bash on WSL but I know vscode isn't/can't access that). And yet it worked just fine for the longest time.

So, my question is, did vscode come with its own git executable? I ask because ever since I set up 2 factor auth on my github account I've been having to manually log in each time I push, it doesn't use my SSH keys stored in username/.ssh like git shell does.

Comment: Show output of `where git` in cmd console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github Desktop installs git for you, typically located "C:\Program Files\Git", which is what VSCode, in your case, is most likely using.

If you refer to the answer from this post:

[VSCode Terminal + Git Bash "command not found" for any command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528451/vscode-terminal-git-bash-command-not-found-for-any-command)

it shows the settings (settings.json) that you need to add to allow for git bash and login to be used.

Hopefully this helps!