# How do I get language specif commands to work in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code and I am trying to run commands in terminal to work with my project. I changed the default terminal to Git Bash but that didn't work. When I run a specific command I get errors. Here is an example for Ruby:

```
$ bundle install
bash: bundle: command not found
```

This occurs whenever I try running a ruby/rails command. I am using Windows, is there a specific setting I need to edit in order to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your VSCode `settings.json` file

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"]
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528451/vscode-terminal-git-bash-command-not-found-for-any-command)